Are "I couldn't iron the drapes" and "I couldn't iron out the drapes" similar in meaning?
I came across this example in thefreedictionary.com

iron something out

Lit. to use a flatiron to make cloth flat or smooth.

I ironed out the drapes.

the verb "iron" means

to make clothes, etc. smooth by using an iron
I'll need to iron that dress before I can wear it.

Are "I couldn't iron the drapes" and "I couldn't iron out the drapes" similar in meaning?
I guess "I couldn't iron the drapes" could mean I didn't know how to iron or I didn't have an iron or my iron was broken
But, "I couldn't iron out the drapes" could mean I actually iron the drapes but was unable to remove the stubborn wrinkles.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Merriam Webster
iron out
verb
ironed out; ironing out; irons out
Synonyms of iron out
transitive verb
1
: to make smooth or flat by or as if by pressing [with an iron]
2
: to resolve or work out a solution to
ironed out their differences

I couldn't iron out the drapes; they were too wrinkled and old.
OR
I couldn't iron out the wrinkles and creases in the drapes.

COMPARE:

Person One: I couldn't iron the drapes.  [couldn't = unable to iron them]
Person Two: Oh really? Why not?
Person One: I hurt my right hand and couldn't use the iron.

OR
I couldn't iron the drapes. I just didn't have time.
So, the two might or might not mean the same thing depending on context.

I have never heard "iron out" with the item (e.g. shirt, tie, trousers, blouse, skirt, drapes) as the direct object, only "creases" and "wrinkles". I couldn't iron out that crease from the blouse, much as I tried.

@TimR: Nope. I said couldn't iron out the drapes  because they were too wrinkled and old. |Step 5: Iron and Replace Sheets on the Bed
If necessary, iron out the sheets so you get a nice, smooth surface while you sleep. However, many beddings are now made with non-creasing fabric, which removes the need to iron the sheets before replacing them onto the bed.| as long as wrinkles etc. are mentioned, it's fine. AND look at that internet hit.

And to iron out the trousers that go with your coat you can make use of the crease head - this acts like a clasp on your garment making it easy to add a proper crease where needed. https://www.ourexternalworld.com/2015/03/how-does-garment-steamer-make-life.html

Once again, a peremptory meaningless "Nope".  What in particular are you disagreeing with?  There's nothing in my comment that you could disagree with. I'm simply making a statement about my experience of having never heard what you say is possible.  That said, how does the "because" change things?  Is the argument that merely mentioning wrinkles somewhere in the conversation licenses the use of "iron out" with the item as direct object?

The author of that ironing article does not appear to be a native speaker of AmE or BrE.  The article talks about ironing "a chiffon sari" and "chiffon dupatta" and contains the phrase "in summers" and is singing the praises of the "Maharaja Steamer" and says that the steamer has "bristles that will brush past your garment" [my emphasis]

I'm disagreeing with what you said "I have never heard "iron out" with the item (e.g. shirt, tie, trousers, blouse, skirt, drapes) as the direct object etc." , It directly precedes my nope. Look, the point is we do say iron out an item as I did followed by creases and wrinkles. So, it is contextualized. So what if the author is Indian? It's fine. And the first one I posted with no link is fine too.

I'm not making any judgments about it other than to say that in all my born days as a speaker of AmE, I have not heard it used that way.  Can you "iron the shirt out"?  When it takes the thing ironed as direct object, can the preposition be stranded?

@TimR But you are making a judgment, you are making a big deal out of it. Of course, one wouldn't say Can you iron the shirt out? FOR Can you iron the shirt? I addressed this fact in my answer. Just because I put creases and wrinkles afterwards does not mean it's wrong at all.
